# CAS does not start using Spring

Tags: spring, cas

I have configured my CAS 5.1.4 and I also generated my self-signed certificate using keytool, I have LDAP for the repository of my users, to run the CAS project I perform these steps:

```
./build.sh clean package
./build.sh copy
./build.sh run
```

Configuration file:

`application.yml` is https://jpst.it/1YrFH

`cas.properties` is https://justpaste.it/7k5ah

The certificate (.keystore) will place you in the folder
`/etc/cas/`

`<MyProject>/etc/cas/`

`<MyProject>/src/main/resources/etc/cas`

It is worth mentioning that I have a CAS project without Spring which runs smoothly but in Spring I get these errors, you can guide me to the solution thanks.
[image]

Comment: The problem was path for keystore Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

- Remove your `application.yml` file.
- Move your keystore file to `/etc/cas` and rename it `thekeystore`.

```sh
11:30 $ ls /etc/cas/thekeystore

Permissions Size User   Group Date Modified Name
.rw-r--r--  2.3k Misagh wheel  9 Apr  2018  /etc/cas/thekeystore
```

Make sure your keystore file is correctly created using the `keytool` tool. If you also need to specify SSL settings such as key alias, do them in the cas.properties file.

> It is worth mentioning that I have a CAS project without Spring which runs smoothly

No, that is incorrect. All versions of the CAS software run with Spring. There does NOT exist a version of the **Apereo CAS software** that runs without Spring. What you *probably* meant is that you have a version of the software that runs without **Spring Boot**. And, your issue has nothing to do with either Spring or Spring Boot; it has to do with misconfiguration of the keystore and SSL settings. Once you fix that, the problem goes away.

Comment: I'm sorry for the time.
The error was the path for the .keystore. About the other CAS, I don't have with APEREO, I just compared the way to generate the certificate since I used the same for the CAS project without Spring and it worked.